# Replace spaces after a dot in the string

Tags: oracle, regexp-replace

I want to write a query in Oracle to remove any spaces after any dot in the string.
example :

```
select 'My name is Pramod. I am writing a query. Today is AUG 16TH.' from dual;
```

output requested is :

```
My name is Pramod.I am writing a query.Today is AUG 16TH.
```

Comment: Please show us your code and indicate where you are having trouble.

Comment: in this case a simple [REPLACE()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions134.htm) would/should do the trick just fine.. Don't start a regex engine if you don't need it?

Comment: @RaymondNijland - That would not help if sometimes there are two (or more) consecutive spaces after a period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works too.

```
select regexp_replace( 'Right.   As @Mathguy said. It won''t work.always' ,'(\.)([[:space:]]*)', '.' )  from dual;
```

Comment: If the string is like this :  'Right<two space>.<two spaces>As Mathguy said. It<two spaces>won''t work.always' and i want 'Right<one space>.<zero spaces>As Mathguy said. It<one space>won''t work.always'                                                  
      so Basically only one space after each word but NO SPACE After ANY DOT in the string

Comment: *"its right. for spaces can also be used : \s"* MIne comment was more meant to look out for making duplicated answers, which you might be downvoted for..

Comment: this regex (\.)([[:space:]]*) does work for your question scenarios

Answer (score 1):

A simple `replace`, based on your simple example:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'My name is Pramod. I am writing a query' from dual)
  3  select replace(col, '. ', '.') result
  4  from test;

RESULT
--------------------------------------
My name is Pramod.I am writing a query

SQL>
```

For not that simple examples:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'My name is Pramod. I am writing a query' from dual union all
  3     select 'Right.   As @Mathguy said. It won''t work.always' from dual
  4    )
  5  select regexp_replace(col, '\. +', '.') result
  6  from test;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
My name is Pramod.I am writing a query
Right.As @Mathguy said.It won't work.always

SQL>
```

Comment: That won't work if sometimes there are two or more consecutive spaces after a period.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select regexp_replace('My name is Pramod. I am writing a query. Today is AUG 16TH.','\.(\s)*','.') 
from dual
```

Sql fiddle [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c73aff/15)

Cheers!!

Comment: What if the string is like below:  'My  name is Pramod.    I am writing a query. Today is AUG 16TH.'             I have to handle extra spaces also after "My"    . I want only one space after each work BUT NO SPACE after dot.

Comment: Please paste the string. Answer is given based on sample data

Comment: It will work. See [sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c73aff/16)

Comment: Yes, I have given answer before littlefoot updated his answer with title: "For not that simple examples:" otherwise I would have not repeated the answer.

Comment: Nevermind mine comment then, i didn't notice your answer and his edit where made around the same time... fair enough +1 to make up for mine comment..

Comment: Thanks @RaymondNijland.

Comment: I want an oracle query that will handle two things:

1) Only ONE space after any word. Remove any extra spaces if any after any word in the string.

2) Do not want to see any spaces if any,  after any "dot or comman or colon or semi-colon" in the string. ZERO spaces after ". or , or ; or :"


ex:
'My  name is Pramod.  I am writing a query,  Today is AUG 16TH: 2019;  X11.'
Requested output:
'My name is Pramod.I am writing a query,Today is AUG 16TH:2019;X11.'

Note: There are two spaces after "My" and two spaces after "I",";",":" and ",".